# How Can I fix Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row in select?

Tags: c#, oracle

Am trying to run this query in Oracle in C# but getting

> Exception: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
select 
msisdn "Msisdn", 
first_name "OtherNames", 
last_name "Surname", 
gender "Gender", 
card_number "CardNumber", 
card_type_v "CardType", 
to_char(CARD_EXPIRY_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "CardExpiryDate", 
to_char(REQUEST_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "Identifier", 
to_char(DATE_OF_BIRTH_D, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "DateOfBirth", 
address "Address" 
from NIA_MOMO_DETAILS 
where REQUEST_DATE > to_timestamp('2022-10-07 13:10:29', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND ROWNUM < 500 ORDER BY REQUEST_DATE ASC
```

But the query runs fine when executed directly on oracle

Comment: Looks like part of the query in your question is missing. The section visible could absolutely return more than one row.

Comment: Trace your session to find *real* problem query

Comment: Error message mentions subquery, but there's no subquery here.

Comment: That is all am executing. Strangely the error appears when I try to scroll for more from sql developer application

Answer (score 0):

After several hours searching for solution, I Just updated this with to_timestamp('2022-10-07 13:10:29', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') with trunc and the issue was solved.

> trunc(to_timestamp('2022-10-07 13:10:29', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))